# Magento 1.9.3.0 product page design is reverted to base/default

Tags: magento1.9.3, product-page, theme-fallback

I have a Magento 1.9.3.0 test shop for which I've created a new theme based on `rwd`. This shop uses a database that's been cloned from the production environment (Magento 1.8.1.0). Everything works very well except this weird bug:

When I visit a product view page the package/theme gets reverted to `base/default` from `rwd/myCustom`.

If I go in Admin and edit the product I was looking at earlier and just hit *"Save"* or *"Save and continue"* even without making any change, then refresh the product page again, the correct theme appears (`rwd/myCustom`)

[image]

I don't have many products (~50) so I could just manually go through them and "fix" them but I am more curious what causes this.

- None of the products have a custom design set.
- I've cleared cache, re-indexed a bunch of times so it's not that.
- I've checked under Systems > Design and there's are no entries there.
- I've tried a mass attribute update (Select All > Actions: Update
  Attributes > Change an attribute for all products > Save) but that
  doesn't seem to fix anything.
- Logs (magento & apache) show nothing when accessing "bugged" product
  pages

Programatically loading and saving a product doesn't fix it.

Comment: as you are talking about the hitting save and it solves the issue, you still have indexing issues, although you reindexed seems still the tables were not indexed correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just figured it out!

Notes:

*The old (production) site is running a package called `oldtheme`.

The new (development) site is running a theme called `myCustom` under the `rwd` package.*

After digging through `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php` and logging the `designPackageExists` function with `Mage::log` I've noticed that Magento was looking for an `oldtheme` package instead of `rwd`.

I did a search in the database and revealed that under `catalog_product_entity_varchar` there were a bunch of entries with the `oldtheme/default` value.
I tracked the entry's `entity_type_id` in the `eav_attributes` table and found that its corresponded to the `custom_design` attribute (even though non of the products had a custom design set for any of the store views).

The fix was removing the offending entries from `catalog_product_entity_varchar`.

Comment: Thanks, Alexandru  it was an old theme in the value field of catalog_product_entity_varchar for attribute custom_design id ( 96 ), You need to remove this date from the table by 

UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_varchar` SET value=NULL WHERE `attribute_id` = 96